# Using JSON File To Animate Unreal Metahumans

Tags: python, animation, unreal-engine4

I am trying to animate a metahuman real-time using Azure TTS and I get facial positions for visemes(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/how-to-speech-synthesis-viseme?pivots=programming-language-python&tabs=3dblendshapes). I am using python for that project and now I have a output animation.json file which has a structure like:
{
{
"Audio_offset":20,
"FrameIndex":0,
"BlendShapes":[
[0.021,0.321,...,0.258],
[0.045,0.234,...,0.288],
...
]]
},
{
"Audio_offset":20,
"FrameIndex":0,
"BlendShapes":[
[0.021,0.321,...,0.258],
[0.045,0.234,...,0.288],
...
]]
}
}
I need to produce animations out of these blendshapes using Blueprints in unreal engine.Is there a way to do it or what are your recommendations?

I haven't get my hands on since I'm a bit clueless on the topic.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look Unreal Livelink app and convert your animation json data to live link facial animation csv data format.
It is not complex, just 52 blendshapes and head, left eye, right eye rotation per frames. In viseme json file, there is 55 blendshapes, first 52 is same as live link 52 blendshapes only by different order, and you just need to convert last 3 rotations (headRoll, leftEyeRoll, rightEyeRoll).

When the csv data is ready, enable plugin named Livelink face importer in your unreal project then import it as a sequence, set your metahuman actor animation mode to ARKit face, it should work.

Comment: thanks for this recommendation yet I find a SDK named Metahumans SDK which does TTS and audio to animation for free I will try to make it work that way. Integrating python with unreal is pain in the a$$ anyway